# Transition table with VueJS

Tags: html-table, vue.js, transition

I tried to continue with the [example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/grid-component.html) on the vuejs website. I tried to add images and a transition state when I sort data.
However it doesn't work. I have tried to add the following line to make it works but it doesn't:

`<tbody name="table-row" is="transition-group">`

Do you have some ideas for me?
https://codepen.io/wooza/pen/wezqXP

Answer (score 31, accepted):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gRmxwJ

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions

> Unlike `<transition>`, it renders an actual element: a `<span>` by
> default. You can change the element that’s rendered with the tag
> attribute.

```
<transition-group tag="tbody" name="table-row">
      <tr v-for="entry in filteredData" :key="entry.name">
      //...
      </tr>
</transition-group>
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to give you a mark but thanks a lot a lot a lot!

Comment: @Woza now you have enough reputation you could accept it